# Dart dependencies conflicts every time I run a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, mobile-development

I have Flutter 3.13.6 and every time I run a Flutter project the build failed because of Dart dependencies conflicts, forcing me to bypass this problem through making separate Pub/Cache folder for each project, so when i start working in a Flutter project I first delete the current Pub/Cache folder and copy the one belongs to the desired project.

This is a serious problem to me as I'm following this approach to prevent wasting Gigabytes of my internet bundle, as there is no unlimited internet service in Egypt. The maximum internet capacity for all internet providers in Egypt is 300 GB only, as well as I have many people at home using the internet so the consumption is very high.

So can anyone help me solving this problem? as "dart pub cache repair" also not working and the conflicts still there.

Comment: Nobody can help you resolve your dependency conflicts if you don't specify what the conflicts are.

Comment: This vary depending on the packages in the project's pubsec.yaml. This problem wasn't exist on the older versions of Flutter

Comment: please add your error message.  what are you getting on the terminal?

Comment: try doing `flutter clean`  ` flutter pub get`  &  `invalid cache restart` and then run

Comment: Give some examples of the conflicts then.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was at work all day.

I encountered a strange thing, I found the projects run smoothly and the problem solved, although the problem repeated all day yesterday.

But if the problem returned, then I will share the error messages here.

Thank you all for your interesting

Comment: Here's an error occured just now: https://i.imgur.com/33HiqCT.png